# Problem updating Connection String in Visual Studio Sql Service Projects

Tags: stored-procedures, visual-studio-2005

I have created a few clr stored procedures and had them setup to our development environment.  I now want to update the connection string on the database tab of the project but its not saving.  Here is the list of things I have done:

1. I checked to make sure that the project file and user project file were not read-only
2. I have deleted the user project unloaded the project and reloaded and the project and created a new connection string

I am not sure what else to do, has anyone else had issues updating database connection string in a Sql Service Project?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2008 doesn't update the connection strings properly when you edit them, it adds a new string instead of replacing them. Look in your app.config file and you might have multiple instances of the string that are named the same.